# Deploying Rails App, NameError: uninitialized constant Foundation::Rails::Generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, foundation

I'm trying to deploy my first Rails app to my test server.  Using Ubuntu, Capistrano, Passenger, Apache.  Rails 4.1.9, Ruby 2.0.0.

Everything seems to pull from Github to my production server okay, but rack returns:  NameError: uninitialized constant Foundation::Rails::Generators when
try to run rake.

Sorry to be such a N00b but I haven't been able to find the problem.

Error generates from Bundler.require(*Rails.groups) in application.rb

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your deployment probably does not run `bundle install` to install the gems your app needs. 
Try adding `require 'bundler/capistrano'` to the top of your deploy.rb to automatically install the gems in your Gemfile.

[Capo.io](http://capo.io/) is a good source when you want to get started with good capistrano recepies btw.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm new to Capistrano.  But I did run bundle install on the production server - does that do the same thing?